# Does any Angular2 GraphQL API Library or comparable datalayer exist?

Tags: angular, graphql

Does any Angular 2 GraphQL API or comparable exist? So thinking of anything like relay but just for Angular2?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer is no. You can implement GraphQL for Angular. There are some great libraries you can import from npm. Or, for that matter, you could write a GraphQL server in any language. There has been significant work in that direction:

https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-graphql

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is one! It's called `angular2-apollo`. You can check it [here](https://github.com/apollostack/angular2-apollo).

This is the Angular2 integration for the [Apollo Client](http://apollostack.com).

Here is [an example app](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/GitHunt-angular2).

Comment: It recently changed the name to `apollo-angular`